# Is it okay for a gentile to join a Christian or an Islamic charity movement?

Tags: gentiles, tzedakah-charity

If a gentile want to spend his free time other than Study Torah and want to join a Charity movement but the problem isnthat all the charity movements he/she knows and are near them is Christian or Islamic. Is it better to join or not to join any of these ?

Comment: "other than Study Torah?"

Comment: @LiquidMetal If someone wants to be a good servant of HaShem, studying might be enhanced by charity work. So Tzedakah is the practice which shows what the Torah teaches. If you have a time to practice what you study then why not ?

Comment: I'm just saying that you're making an assumption that Hashem wants gentiles to study Torah.  Unless you're referring to study of the laws of the 7 mitzvos, I don't know if that's true.

Also, would this depend on if the said religion is considered Avoda Zara for a gentile?

Comment: @LiquidMetal that's exactly why I am asking this question. Because Christianity is considered avoda zara. But even if Islam isn't, is it still permitted ?